# The regular expression used in JavaScript does not work in Java

Tags: regex

```
replace(/[.?+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, '\\$&');
```

But it doesn't work in Java.
So I changed the code as follows.

```
replace(/[.?+^$[\\]\\\\(){}|-]/g, '\\\\$&');
```

It doesn't work when I change it. Please help me :(

Comment: In java, you need to use double quotes instead of quote slashes for regex: `"[.?+^$[\\]\\\\(){}|-]"`. Also, if you want to replace all occurrences, you need to use [`String.replaceAll`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

replaceAll(?"[?]+^$[\\]\\\\\(){}|-", "\\\\$&") results in a blank space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) does not take a regex in the constructor, for that you need [replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

But as you are using the `/g` flag in Javascript for all replacements, you can use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

In Javascript, this part `$&` in the replacement points to the full match.

So you want to replace the full match (which is one of these characters `[.?+^$[\]\\(){}|-]`) prepended by a `\`

In Java you can use `$0` instead to refer to the full match.

You can also escape the opening square bracket in the character class `\\[`

For example

```
System.out.println("{test?test^}".replaceAll("[.?+^$\\[\\]\\\\()\\{}|-]", "\\\\$0"));
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/THEQFH)

**Output**

```
\{test\?test\^\}
```

The same output in Javascript

```js
console.log("{test?test^}".replace(/[.?+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, '\\$&'));
```